# VBA Syntax for Large Selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table which I regularly add data to on a daily basis. Sometimes a new data row is needed so I insert a new row. I then use VLOOKUPS on my table to insert the data for my columns.

However, when I carry my VLOOKUP formula for the entire column each cell carries the same format as the cell with the original formula.

I have to select each row and skip a row to then select my desired format. Instead of selecting each row and then changing the format to either no highlight or highlight blue I decided to write a macro that will select all even rows in my table and format those rows with no highlight (All odd rows are highlighted blue).

Since I have such a large collection of rows, how can I keep my VBA code so that it fits into a readable format instead of a long horizontal list?

Please see my code and the error below:

```
Range("E12:W12,E14:W14,E16:W16,E18:W18,E20:W20,E22:W22,E24:W24,E26:W26,E28:W28, _
    E30:W30,E32:W32,E34:W34,E36:W36,E38:W38,E40:W40, _
    E42:W42,E44:W44,E46:W46,E48:W48,E50:W50,E52:W52,E54:W54,E54:W54,E56:W56,E58:W58, _
    E60:W60,E62:W62,E64:W64,E66:W66,E68:W68,E70:W70,E72:W72,E74:W74,E76:W76,E78:W78, _
    E80:W80,E82:W82,E84:W84,E86:W86,E88:W88,E90:W90,E92:W92").Select

With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0

ERROR: Syntax Error
```

Comment: Each new line needs to start with a `"` and before the underscore you need a `" & ` to concatenate large string like this. However, I think this will still not work.

Comment: This won't work - you can't have a range reference longer than 255 characters. Maybe use `Intersect` on the rows/columns you want. Or if there's a pattern, maybe loop through rows.

Comment: How can I select all even rows starting from E12:W12 through E92:W92 if I can't do so while using a range reference?

Comment: Don't select, just use a loop. Or actually use a built in Excel table and apply the format there. You can do alternating colors, no need for VBA to format.

Comment: How can I loop to select even rows? Would I use "offset(2,0)" until cell = E94?

I can't use the predesigned Excel tables since I add one column everyday. I'll have to continuously reapply the table for the additional columns (Already at over 20 columns)

Comment: built-in tables should allow for appending columns... have you tried it?

Comment: Built in table will also change the structure of my current table. I don't need my table to function as an Excel Table object. I just need the rows to be distinguishable for user legibility.

Comment: How about Conditional formatting with formula

Comment: Each row is either not highlighted or highlighted in blue. I could write two different VLOOKUPS but then the formula for cell references might be a bit inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not quite clear what you are trying to achieve from that code... create your formulas for those ranges, or format your table... might help to clarify your question.

Meanwhile see if this helps:

```vb
Sub loopnsub()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Dim R As Long

For R = 12 To lRow Step 2
    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(R, "E"), ws.Cells(R, "W"))
        .Interior = 65535 'set your background colour here
        .Font.Color = -16776961 'set your font colour here
        'etc, etc, etc
    End With
Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: This is by far the best code in terms of comprehensiveness and succinctness. Thank you FAB!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()

    'Change these as necessary
    Const StartRow As Long = 12
    Const FinalRow As Long = 92
    Const RangeCols As String = "E:W"
    Const RowStep As Long = 2

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFormula As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rFormula = Intersect(ws.Columns(RangeCols), ws.Rows(StartRow))

    For i = StartRow + RowStep To FinalRow Step RowStep
        Set rFormula = Union(rFormula, Intersect(ws.Columns("E:W"), ws.Rows(i)))
    Next i

    'Do something with your created range
    rFormula.Formula = "=""MyFormulaHere"""

End Sub
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but your code is similiar to FAB. I used FAB since his code was pretty comprehensible and can be easily modified.

Answer (score 1):

Each new line needs to start with a `"` and before the underscore you need a `" &` to concatenate large string like this. However, I think this will still not work because you can define a range address that long anyways, as there are some [undocumented limitations to the length of the string](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/issues/49#issuecomment-484546661) that you can pass to the `Range`, and your construct exceeds this limit.

Note that you can actually build ranges (e.g., using `Union`) that exceed this limit, but if you then query that range's `Address`, per the issue above, it will be silently truncated.

```
Dim addr As String

addr = "E12:W12,E14:W14,E16:W16,E18:W18,E20:W20,E22:W22,E24:W24,E26:W26,E28:W28," & _
    "E30:W30,E32:W32,E34:W34,E36:W36,E38:W38,E40:W40," & _
    "E42:W42,E44:W44,E46:W46,E48:W48,E50:W50,E52:W52,E54:W54,E54:W54,E56:W56,E58:W58," & _
    "E60:W60,E62:W62,E64:W64,E66:W66,E68:W68,E70:W70,E72:W72,E74:W74,E76:W76,E78:W78," & _
    "E80:W80,E82:W82,E84:W84,E86:W86,E88:W88,E90:W90,E92:W92"

Debug.Print Len(addr)  '### This will print 335, versus the limit of 255
```

So, even if you construct your address correctly (above), you still can't use this to define a range.

Ultimately, this should probably be handled via `Union` or stepwise iteration. But it's unclear what you need to do with these ranges.

Comment: I edited my question to show what my selection was intended to achieve.

Comment: @Computer_Nerd cheers, looks like you've got a solution already (stepwise iteration, that I mentioned, is what Fab's answer implements for you).

Answer (score 0):

Just to be as close as possible to your original post: What about combining the ranges

```
Union(Range("E12:W12,E14:W14,E16:W16,E18:W18,E20:W20,E22:W22,E24:W24,E26:W26,E28:W28," & _
    "E30:W30,E32:W32,E34:W34,E36:W36,E38:W38,E40:W40," & _
    "E42:W42,E44:W44,E46:W46,E48:W48,E50:W50,E52:W52,E54:W54,E54:W54,E56:W56,E58:W58"), _
    Range("E60:W60,E62:W62,E64:W64,E66:W66,E68:W68,E70:W70,E72:W72,E74:W74,E76:W76,E78:W78," & _
    "E80:W80,E82:W82,E84:W84,E86:W86,E88:W88,E90:W90,E92:W92")).Select
```

**Side notes:**

Your version in OP ends with a `"`, broken lines have to reflect at least full string parts that have to be connected by `&` and you have to pay attention to the 255 character Limitation @BigBen mentioned. Another method would be to enter  range parts into several cells and connect them.

Consider to avoid `.Select` as in most cases it isn't needed and can be addressed directly.